# Format XML returns empty

Tags: xml, powershell, format

I am trying to use PowerShell to format a messy XML file to a file with indentation where every tag starts on a new line.

The input file looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
<RESULT>
<HEADER><ACCOUNT>035574623593</ACCOUNT><DATE_FROM>20150101</DATE_FROM><DATE_TO>20150526</DATE_TO><DATE_EQUAL></DATE_EQUAL><HD_DATIN>2015-11-27 15:16:52</HD_DATIN><HD_START>2015-11-27 15:16:52</HD_START><HD_ENGINE>WCV00228</HD_ENGINE><HD_QUERYID>984</HD_QUERYID></HEADER>
<FOOTER><FT_STATUS>NF</FT_STATUS><FT_RECORDS>2</FT_RECORDS><FT_SIZE>282</FT_SIZE><FT_ORDER>1</FT_ORDER><FT_STOP>2015-11-27 15:16:53</FT_STOP></FOOTER>
</RESULT>
```

This is a piece of my code where the formatting takes place:

```psh
function Format-XML {
  Param ([string]$xmlfile)

  $Doc=New-Object System.Xml.XmlDataDocument
  $doc.Load($xmlfile)
  $sw = New-Object System.IO.StringWriter
  $settings = New-Object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
  $settings.NewLineOnAttributes = $false
  $settings.Indent = 1
  $settings.NewLineOnAttributes = $true
  $writer = [System.xml.XmlWriter]::Create($sw, $settings)
  $doc.WriteContentTo($writer)
  $sw.ToString()
}

Format-XML ("${app}se-xf-out\UH99DEFI.BEMVS000.U$datum.T$counter") > "${app}se-xf-out\UH99DEFI.BEMVS001.U$datum.T$counter"
```

Can someone help me? The output file is empty (but still 1kb).

Answer (score 1):

From the [Microsoft blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/01/18/format-xml.aspx), this seems to work just fine:

```
$Stuff = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
<RESULT>
<HEADER><ACCOUNT>035574623593</ACCOUNT><DATE_FROM>20150101</DATE_FROM><DATE_TO>20150526</DATE_TO><DATE_EQUAL></DATE_EQUAL><HD_DATIN>2015-11-27 15:16:52</HD_DATIN><HD_START>2015-11-27 15:16:52</HD_START><HD_ENGINE>WCV00228</HD_ENGINE><HD_QUERYID>984</HD_QUERYID></HEADER>
<FOOTER><FT_STATUS>NF</FT_STATUS><FT_RECORDS>2</FT_RECORDS><FT_SIZE>282</FT_SIZE><FT_ORDER>1</FT_ORDER><FT_STOP>2015-11-27 15:16:53</FT_STOP></FOOTER>
</RESULT>
"@

Function Format-XML ([xml]$xml, $indent=2) { 
    $StringWriter = New-Object System.IO.StringWriter 
    $XmlWriter = New-Object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter $StringWriter 
    $xmlWriter.Formatting = "indented" 
    $xmlWriter.Indentation = $Indent 
    $xml.WriteContentTo($XmlWriter) 
    $XmlWriter.Flush() 
    $StringWriter.Flush() 
    Write-Output $StringWriter.ToString() 
}
Format-XML ([xml]$Stuff) -indent 3
```

Generated output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
<RESULT>
   <HEADER>
      <ACCOUNT>035574623593</ACCOUNT>
      <DATE_FROM>20150101</DATE_FROM>
      <DATE_TO>20150526</DATE_TO>
      <DATE_EQUAL>
      </DATE_EQUAL>
      <HD_DATIN>2015-11-27 15:16:52</HD_DATIN>
      <HD_START>2015-11-27 15:16:52</HD_START>
      <HD_ENGINE>WCV00228</HD_ENGINE>
      <HD_QUERYID>984</HD_QUERYID>
   </HEADER>
   <FOOTER>
      <FT_STATUS>NF</FT_STATUS>
      <FT_RECORDS>2</FT_RECORDS>
      <FT_SIZE>282</FT_SIZE>
      <FT_ORDER>1</FT_ORDER>
      <FT_STOP>2015-11-27 15:16:53</FT_STOP>
   </FOOTER>
</RESULT>
```